# .ASPX Has Changed Check

Tags: c#, .net

I've checked many other examples and can't quite find what i'm looking for, a little background. I'm working on a solution to prevent having a browser window open.

When the target URL is looked at the Header  is always the same until the javascript in the page does it work to see if a new message has been posted. at that point the  is dynamically changed based on if you have the page active and have not clicked an acknowledge button which the java script changes the  back to No new messages.

My ultimate goal is to check the site which is a .ASPX file, it needs to authenticate to view it. I've tried this code to check the size of the file hoping to detect just a change in the over all size, but its finding size changes to frequently when there is no real update.

Any ideas?

```
long bbssize = 0; // start size.
long bbssizewas = 0; // start size.
```

encased in a tick...

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.fictionalsite.com/Main_View.aspx");
req.Method = "HEAD";
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());
long lenth = resp.ContentLength;
bbssize = lenth;
if (bbssize != bbssizewas) // checks for change.
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Lime; // changes color to green.
    bbssizewas = bbssize; // sets new value to check.
}
```

Comment: Voted down until you write meaningful English text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason my script was working incorrectly, the .ASPX location was fluctuating in bytes by about 11 every few seconds making it looks like there was a change.

I adjusted the code to add "bytes" to account for it causing the if statement to only trip if a significant change had occoured.

// Dictated early in the program...

```
    long timerisat = 0;
    long timerwas = 0;
```

// Encased in a timer tick.

```
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.OpenRead("http://example.com/thewebpage.aspx");
            Int64 bytes_total = Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
            timerisat = bytes_total;

            if (timerisat > timerwas) // checks for change.
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.DarkRed; // changes color to green.
                button7.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
                timerwas = timerisat + 20; // sets new value to check. (adds 20 bytes)         
                // Notification pops up on tooltip.
                this.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "MyTSC Bulletin Board - Updated";
                this.notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Workspace";
                this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10);
            }
```